# MVC 4 Getting the current Area, Controller and Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Layout.cshtml I call RenderAction to show the menu for every page request:

```
 Html.RenderAction("NiceMenu", "Widgets", new {area = ""});
```

The WidgetController needs to know the parent executing **Controller** and **Action** calling it so that it can render the menu with the right item highlighted.

How can the Widget **Controller's** NiceMenu action know this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ParentActionViewContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.parentactionviewcontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property of [ViewContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in the child action's view:

```
var parentRouteValues = ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values;
@Html.RenderAction("NiceMenu", "Widgets",
             new
             {
                 area = parentRouteValues["area"],
                 controller = parentRouteValues["controller"],
                 action = parentRouteValues["action"]
             })
```

Answer (score 11):

this is how we do it

```
var action = (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] ?? "").ToString().ToLower();
var controller = (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] ?? "").ToString().ToLower();
var area = (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] ?? "").ToString().ToLower();
```

Comment: That's really helpful to get the context of the Widget, but how do I get the main executing page action/controller/area?